# Snakemake: MissingInputException - Missing input files for rule all

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to make a snakemake workflow for whatshap haplotype caller but I am struggling with MissingInputException errors. This is what I get:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 9 of /srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/whatshap/phased_illumina_FILT5/snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
saturna/saturna_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
stratos/stratos_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
12NAE3/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
verdi/verdi_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
wotan/wotan_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
avarna/avarna_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
avenue/avenue_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
seresta/seresta_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
15NOH7/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
```

If I remove "rule all" and try to produce a single file I get this error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce 12NAE3/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

What am I missing? I am new to snakemake so maybe (hopefully) it's just a basic mistake. Here is my code:

```
shell.prefix("module load whatshap/1.1-foss-2020b-Python-3.8.6; module load BCFtools/1.11-GCC-10.2.0; ")

reference = "/srv/KLN/users/esv/Reference/DM_v6/DM_1-3_516_R44_potato_genome_assembly.v6.1.fa"
samples= ['12NAE3', '15NOH7', 'avarna', 'avenue', 'Kuras', 'saturna', 'seresta', 'stratos', 'verdi', 'wotan', 'ydun']
chroms= ['chr01','chr02','chr03','chr04','chr05','chr06','chr07','chr08','chr09','chr10','chr11','chr12']

rule all:
    input:  
        "12NAE3/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "15NOH7/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "avarna/avarna_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "avenue/avenue_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "Kuras/Kuras_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "saturna/saturna_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "seresta/seresta_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "stratos/stratos_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "verdi/verdi_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "wotan/wotan_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz",
        "ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz"


rule HaplotypeCalling:
    input:
        reference = reference,
        vcf = "/srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/snakemake/2110_variantcalling/results/variants/filtered/FILT5/variants_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf",
        bam = "/srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/Data/Illumina/DM_v6/BAM/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "temp/{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf"
    params:
        chroms = chroms
    shell:
        "whatshap polyphase --ploidy 4 -o {output} --reference {input.reference} {input.vcf} {input.bam} --sample {wildcards.sample} --chromosome {params.chroms}"


rule SplitVCF:
    input:
        "temp/{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf"
    output:
        "{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf"
    shell:
        "bcftools view -s {wildcards.sample} -o {output} {input}"
        

rule ConcatVCF:
    input:
        expand("{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf", sample=samples, chrom=chroms)
    output:
        "{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf"
    shell:
        "bcftools concat {input} -o {output}"


rule GZipVCF:
    input:
        "{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf"    
    output:
        "{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz"
    shell:
        "bgzip -c {input} > {output}"
```

Edit: the commands I expect for each sample are these, assuming that I only have two chromosomes (chr01 and chr02) (the example is for sample ydun):

```
#rule HaplotypeCalling
whatshap polyphase --ploidy 4 -o temp/ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf --reference /srv/KLN/users/esv/Reference/DM_v6/DM_1-3_516_R44_potato_genome_assembly.v6.1.fa /srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/snakemake/2110_variantcalling/results/variants/filtered/FILT5/variants_FILT5_chr01.vcf /srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/Data/Illumina/DM_v6/BAM/ydun.bam --sample ydun --chromosome chr01
whatshap polyphase --ploidy 4 -o temp/ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf --reference /srv/KLN/users/esv/Reference/DM_v6/DM_1-3_516_R44_potato_genome_assembly.v6.1.fa /srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/snakemake/2110_variantcalling/results/variants/filtered/FILT5/variants_FILT5_chr02.vcf /srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/Data/Illumina/DM_v6/BAM/ydun.bam --sample ydun --chromosome chr02

#rule SplitVCF
bcftools view -s ydun -o ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf temp/ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf

#rule ConcatVCF
bcftools concat ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf -o ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf

#rule GZipVCF
bgzip -c ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf > ydun/ydun_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz
```

Comment: Could be a copy/paste error, but your inputs and outputs should just be a string, without the `, sample=samples` part.  I'm also confused by the non-formatting wildcards `{{sample}}` throughout.  Can you write out the commands you expect to run for a single sample?  That would help troubleshoot your workflow.

Comment: @TroyComi You're right, in my attempts to fix the error I put in `, sample=samples` in everything, I guess I only need it in the `expand()` function. Regarding the `{{sample}}`, I read somewhere that it can be used if snakemake is not to make every combination, for example ydun/Kuras and Kuras/ydun if that makes sense - but I might be mistaken. I have added the expected commands in the post.

Comment: @TroyComi I am a bit embarrassed, I tried to delete the double braces and now the script works! Thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected commands, here is my attempt at refactoring your workflow.  I've commented to explain the changes.

```
# moved shell prefix to envmodules directive
# https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#using-environment-modules
# that's better for if you need a different set of modules later

reference = "/srv/KLN/users/esv/Reference/DM_v6/DM_1-3_516_R44_potato_genome_assembly.v6.1.fa"
samples= ['12NAE3', '15NOH7', 'avarna', 'avenue', 'Kuras', 'saturna', 'seresta', 'stratos', 'verdi', 'wotan', 'ydun']
chroms= [f'chr{chrom:02}' for chrom in range(1, 13)]

# place filenames together or (better) in a config.yaml
phased_output = '{sample}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz'
variants = '/srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/snakemake/2110_variantcalling/results/variants/filtered/FILT5/variants_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf'
sample_bam = '/srv/KLN/users/esv/KRISPS/Data/Illumina/DM_v6/BAM/{sample}.bam'
temp_vcf = 'temp/{sample}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf'
split_vcf = '{sample}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf'


# don't repeat yourself with sample names or phased output
# using expand makes it easier to add new samples later or change your
# filename
rule all:
    input:  
        expand(phased_output, sample=samples)

# using variables for filenames makes rules clearer
# Based on your sample, I think you should pass in wildcards.chrom
# instead of the chroms list
# For shell, I like to format the calls with an option per line
# it makes it easier to see all options and change or remove them.
# snakemake will combine all the lines so note the spaces at the end of
# each line!
rule HaplotypeCalling:
    input:
        reference = reference,
        vcf = variants,
        bam = sample_bam,
    output:
        temp_vcf
    envmodules:
        'whatshap/1.1-foss-2020b-Python-3.8.6'
    shell:
        "whatshap polyphase "
            "--ploidy 4 "
            "-o {output} "
            "--sample {wildcards.sample} "
            "--chromosome {wildcards.chroms}"
            "--reference {input.reference} {input.vcf} {input.bam} "

# options before arguments
rule SplitVCF:
    input:
        temp_vcf
    output:
        split_vcf
    envmodules:
        'BCFtools/1.11-GCC-10.2.0'
    shell:
        "bcftools view "
            "-s {wildcards.sample} "
            "-o {output} "
            "{input}"
        
# use output type option of bcf tools to skip the bgzip step
rule ConcatVCF:
    input:
        expand(split_vcf, chrom=chroms, allow_missing=true)
    output:
        phased_output
    envmodules:
        'BCFtools/1.11-GCC-10.2.0'
    shell:
        "bcftools concat "
            "-o {output} "
            "-O z "  # compressed vcf output
            "{input} "
```

Not tested but that's my first pass at it!

Spend some time with the rules page on the documentation and work through the tutorial.  Wildcards are important but really subtle.  Here's some materials for a [workshop](https://github.com/troycomi/snakemake-training) I give.  It's a little dated but the core material is still good.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it's very useful! I've tested it and it works - although I still have to use the double braces around `sample` in the expand function in the input in rule ConcatVCF, otherwise it will try to concatenate all the input files instead of one file per sample. I'll definitely take a look at the workshop, thanks!

Comment: Whoops, there was a double curly brace around sample in temp_vcf.  Edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry to spam.  Just looked over your other comments on concatVCF.  What you want is to combine all chromosomes for one sample.  What I had written was combining all chromosomes and samples.  I've edited to use allow_missing in expand; it's the same effect as using double curly braces but has a few advantages for variable filenames and adding wildcards later.  The double curly braces *were* required for that one step.  Let me know if that's not clear and I can expand my answer to explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

Troy Comi has already answered your question in comments, but I will explain it further.

Indeed, removing double braces will help. The difference between single and double braces is that double braces escape the symbol `'{'` and `'}'`. In other words whenever Snakemake encounters a string like this one `"{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz"` in the output section, it treats `{sample}` as a wildcard and `{{sample}}` as a string `"{sample}"`. So it tries to find the files like `{sample}/saturna_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf.gz` which it definitely fails to find.

The problem is quite different in case of using this string in the `expand` function:

```py
expand("{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf", sample=samples, chrom=chroms)
```

Here the function replaces the `{sample}` and `{chrom}` with the values from the lists you provide as parameters `samples` and `chroms`. The `{{sample}}` is being converted to the string `"{sample}"`, but that is not the end of the story. This result of the conversion `"{sample}"` is being treated as a wildcard `{sample}`. For example, consider the rule:

```py
samples = ['12NAE3', '15NOH7']
chroms = ['chr01','chr02']

rule ConcatVCF:
    input:
        expand("{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf", sample=samples, chrom=chroms)
    output:
        "{{sample}}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf"
```

This rule is equivalent to this one, where `{wildcard}` is actual wildcard (so the name is irrelevant), and `{{sample}}` is a string `"{sample}"`:

```py
rule ConcatVCF:
    input:
        "{wildcard}/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf",
        "{wildcard}/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf",
        "{wildcard}/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf",
        "{wildcard}/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf"
    output:
        "{{sample}}/{wildcard}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf"
```

That is definitely not what you meant. Removing double braces you make this rule equivalent to:

```py
rule ConcatVCF:
    input:
        "12NAE3/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf",
        "12NAE3/12NAE3_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf",
        "15NOH7/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr01.vcf",
        "15NOH7/15NOH7_phased_illumina_FILT5_chr02.vcf"
    output:
        "{wildcard}/{wildcard}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf"
```

Comment: Thank you for that thorough explanation, it makes sense. However, in rule ConcatVCF, I still believe I need something or else it will try to concat all input files into one file - what I want is one concatenated file per sample. If I put the double braces around sample in input but not output I get the desired output - but only in this one rule. Like this: `input: expand("{{sample}}/{{sample}}_phased_illumina_FILT5_{chrom}.vcf", chrom=chroms)`
`output: "{sample}/{sample}_phased_illumina_FILT5.vcf" `

Comment: Please ask a separate question.